# installing older angular version 5?

Tags: angular, installation, angular5, angular-cli, downgrade

I was working on personal project which was in Angular 5. Due to some reason I have changed my device, how could I install Angular 5 in my new device since there is new version is available, Is there any way to install Angular 5 instead Angular 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli  
npm install -g @angular/cli@5.0.0
```

but even install the lates angular cli will not effect your old project , just you will get a warning when you try to serve the project.

Happy coding

Comment: For Angular 5: `npm install -g @angular/cli@1`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero when I used cli@1 , I got installed 1.7.4 version of angular cli ?

Comment: @Nadee this `npm i @angular/cli@1` will install the lates version of cli 1.x.x if you want version 5.x.x try this way `npm i @angular/cli@5` 

Comment: @YosvelQuintero For latest verion of Angular cli 5: `npm install -g @angular/cli@5` 

Answer (score 1):

`npm install @angular/<module>@5`

will install the most recent version that satisfies the requirements, just replace the  with the angular submodule.

Alternatively, go to your package.json file and specify e.g. "5.x.x" as the version for your angular dependencies. Run `npm install` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Anyone that comes across this, there's no `@angular/cli@5` at the time of this answer. Use version 1.x.x instead.

`npm i @angular/cli@1` or `yarn add @angular.cli@1`